# What is a clean pythonic method to find a set of sequential constant values in a pd.dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am looking for a method to flag sequential constant values (e.g. n), whom successively are constant, in a pd.dataframe (e.g. df).

I have written some code by which a value will be flagged if its differences with the n/2 next and n/2 previous data point are zero.

```
n = 5         # the minimum number of sequential constant values  

#to create a adatframe example
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25), index=pd.date_range(start='2010-1-1',end='2010-1-2',freq='H'), columns=['value'])

#to modify the dataframe to have several sets of constant values
df[1:10]=23
df[20:26]=10
df[15:17]=15
for i in np.arange(1, int(n/2)):
    # to calcualte the difference between value and ith previous values
    df_diff['delta_' + str(i)] = (df['value'].diff(periods=i)).abs()
    # to calcualte the difference between value and ith next values
    df_diff['delta_' + str(-i)] = (df['value'].diff(periods=-i)).abs()

# to filter the results (e.g. as a boolean)
result_1 = (df_diff[:] <= 0).all(axis=1)
result_2 = (df_diff[:] <= 0).any(axis=1)
```

The result_1 and results_2 in this example do not provide the right answer.

What I expect is:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00    False
2010-01-01 01:00:00     True
2010-01-01 02:00:00     True
2010-01-01 03:00:00     True
2010-01-01 04:00:00     True
2010-01-01 05:00:00     True
2010-01-01 06:00:00     True
2010-01-01 07:00:00     True
2010-01-01 08:00:00     True
2010-01-01 09:00:00     True
2010-01-01 10:00:00    False
2010-01-01 11:00:00    False
2010-01-01 12:00:00    False
2010-01-01 13:00:00    False
2010-01-01 14:00:00    False
2010-01-01 15:00:00    False
2010-01-01 16:00:00    False
2010-01-01 17:00:00    False
2010-01-01 18:00:00    False
2010-01-01 19:00:00    False
2010-01-01 20:00:00     True
2010-01-01 21:00:00     True
2010-01-01 22:00:00     True
2010-01-01 23:00:00     True
2010-01-02 00:00:00     True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with grouper being [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), [`.ne(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) then [`.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df.groupby(df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum())['value'].transform('size').ge(n)
```

[out]

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00    False
2010-01-01 01:00:00     True
2010-01-01 02:00:00     True
2010-01-01 03:00:00     True
2010-01-01 04:00:00     True
2010-01-01 05:00:00     True
2010-01-01 06:00:00     True
2010-01-01 07:00:00     True
2010-01-01 08:00:00     True
2010-01-01 09:00:00     True
2010-01-01 10:00:00    False
2010-01-01 11:00:00    False
2010-01-01 12:00:00    False
2010-01-01 13:00:00    False
2010-01-01 14:00:00    False
2010-01-01 15:00:00    False
2010-01-01 16:00:00    False
2010-01-01 17:00:00    False
2010-01-01 18:00:00    False
2010-01-01 19:00:00    False
2010-01-01 20:00:00     True
2010-01-01 21:00:00     True
2010-01-01 22:00:00     True
2010-01-01 23:00:00     True
2010-01-02 00:00:00     True
Freq: H, Name: value, dtype: bool
```

#### Explanation

The series we group by, will be the contiguous groups of equal values:

```
s = df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

2010-01-01 00:00:00     1
2010-01-01 01:00:00     2
2010-01-01 02:00:00     2
2010-01-01 03:00:00     2
2010-01-01 04:00:00     2
2010-01-01 05:00:00     2
2010-01-01 06:00:00     2
2010-01-01 07:00:00     2
2010-01-01 08:00:00     2
2010-01-01 09:00:00     2
2010-01-01 10:00:00     3
2010-01-01 11:00:00     4
2010-01-01 12:00:00     5
2010-01-01 13:00:00     6
2010-01-01 14:00:00     7
2010-01-01 15:00:00     8
2010-01-01 16:00:00     8
2010-01-01 17:00:00     9
2010-01-01 18:00:00    10
2010-01-01 19:00:00    11
2010-01-01 20:00:00    12
2010-01-01 21:00:00    12
2010-01-01 22:00:00    12
2010-01-01 23:00:00    12
2010-01-02 00:00:00    12
Freq: H, Name: value, dtype: int32
```

When you groupby these 'group id', using `transform` to return an object the same shape as original `DataFrame`, aggregating to 'size', you get:

```
s.groupby(s).transform('size')

2010-01-01 00:00:00    1
2010-01-01 01:00:00    9
2010-01-01 02:00:00    9
2010-01-01 03:00:00    9
2010-01-01 04:00:00    9
2010-01-01 05:00:00    9
2010-01-01 06:00:00    9
2010-01-01 07:00:00    9
2010-01-01 08:00:00    9
2010-01-01 09:00:00    9
2010-01-01 10:00:00    1
2010-01-01 11:00:00    1
2010-01-01 12:00:00    1
2010-01-01 13:00:00    1
2010-01-01 14:00:00    1
2010-01-01 15:00:00    2
2010-01-01 16:00:00    2
2010-01-01 17:00:00    1
2010-01-01 18:00:00    1
2010-01-01 19:00:00    1
2010-01-01 20:00:00    5
2010-01-01 21:00:00    5
2010-01-01 22:00:00    5
2010-01-01 23:00:00    5
2010-01-02 00:00:00    5
Freq: H, Name: value, dtype: int64
```

From here, it's a simple [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) (`>=`) comparison with your value `n`

Answer (score 0):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]
})

df
#    brand     style   rating
# 0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
# 1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
# 2  Indomie   cup     3.5
# 3  Indomie   pack    15.0
# 4  Indomie   pack     5.0

df.duplicated(keep=False)
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     False
# 3     False
# 4     False
# dtype: bool
```